# How can I disabled/enable multiple buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following script to move a `<tr>` from any position in a table to the top of that table. This happens after an ajax form is submitted. The form's--not the button's--class is "top"

```
$(".top").click(function() {
    var thisRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    var firstRow = thisRow.parent().find("tr:first").not(thisRow);
    thisRow.insertBefore(firstRow);
});
```

Once an item reaches the top of the table, I would like to disable the `Send Item To Top` button. The problem becomes complicated because there are two other buttons in each `<tr>`: `Move Item Up By One` and `Move Item Down By One` (both ajax, too)

Once a `<tr>` is moved to the top, I would like to disable the `Move Item Up By One` along with the `Send Item To Top` button. In addition, I would like to re-enable both of them when the `Move Item Down By One` is clicked.

The following script is being used to swap the `<tr>`'s positions when it's moved up/down by one.

**NOTE: I can NOT assign any of my buttons an id or a class because their forms are dynamically generated. I can only assign the form an ID or a class.**

```
// Move item down/up
$(".up,.down").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr id="item_168" class="element168">
    <td><form action=".." class="top..." method="post" onsubmit="..."><input onclick="" type="submit" value="&uarr;" /></form></td>
    <td class="action"><form action="up..." class="up" method="post" onsubmit="..."><input onclick="" type="submit" value="&uarr;" /></form></td>
    <td class="action"><form action="down..." class="down" method="post" onsubmit="..." title="Move one"><input onclick="" type="submit" value="&darr;" /></form></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please give your browser interpreted HTML structure as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite new to jQuery, but can you do

```
$(row).find('.up,.top').find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

Comment: That works if you take out the '[type=button]'... thanks, I got this work work in two situations... moving an item to the top, and moving it down. I can try and figure out how to do it when the "move item up" button reaches the top... please edit your answer to reflect the [type=input] part so i can accept it.

Comment: I'd prefer, if possible, to edit it so the type is correct... Can you show me the HTML for one of your buttons?

Comment: Chris, sure, I guess the type only needs to be submit instead of button... <form action="path" class="top" method="post" onsubmit="$.ajax({ dataType: 'script', type: 'post', url: 'path', data: $(this).serialize(), success: function(data, textStatus){$(this).attr('disabled','false');}, beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest){$(this).attr('disabled','true');}}); return false;" text="&uarr;"><input onclick="" type="submit" value="&uarr;" /></form>

Answer (score 1):

Here's the event handlers broken down into two (for readability):

```
$('#yourTableID').delegate('.up', 'click', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var index = row.index();

  if(index  != 0) {
    row.insertBefore(row.prev());

    if(index == 1) { 
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  } 

})
.delegate('.down', 'click', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var index = row.index();

  if(index  < row.siblings().length) {
    row.insertAfter(row.next());

    if(index + 1 == row.siblings().length) {
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }

});
```

EDIT: changed row.insertAfter(row.prev()) to row.insertAfter(row.next()).  Ooops.

Also, here's the fiddle to check it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/pn3MN/

Comment: Thanks John, but the button's remain disabled once they become disabled. Moving the down does not re-enable them. Also, there's the additional button of move item to top :/

Comment: Yea I started playing with it in fiddle and noticed I didn't do the full circle.  But who comes to SO to be given the entire solution right? :)  Hopefully this helped with the concept and you weren't looking to be given the answer :p

Comment: Haha! Amateurs like me do :D... but the above one line solution worked. For the most part. One more mod and it's done. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

give your buttons classes or IDs and use these hooks to enable / disable / hide your buttons

Comment: Moin, it's not an option since the forms are dynamically generated via a my frameworks API, and I can only apply a class to the form.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not even sure where the code would go in my example.